# Reduce the size of the iPhone Simulator window?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, scale, xcode9, simulator

Is it possible to resize the iPhone Simulator?  I'm using screen capture software to record a demo of my iPhone application, and it would be handy to be able to resize the iPhone Simulator window.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not turn on Spaces and put the Simulator in its own space?

Comment: hey I think you should change the accepted answer... the one suggested by lekafir works exactly :-)

Comment: In any case, my answer is from 4 years ago and is no longer relevant at all.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You should try *cmd 2* or *cmd 3* on your keyboard to scale down.

And *cmd 1* to get back to the original scale.

Comment: In Xcode 6.3 and above, just press cmd 5 (25% scale) or cmd 4 (33% scale). Or in Window > Scale

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

This is no longer the correct answer.

---

Unfortunately no, it must maintain that size. We had the same issue. I wish I could give you a more complete answer, however it seems reasonable for the accurate rendering profiling that it maintains 1-to-1 pixel ratio, otherwise it would have to sub-sample the pixels, causing the profiling to be incorrect.

Comment: Since this question has been marked as correct, the iOS SDK has improved quite a bit, lefakir's answer is now valid and mine is incorrect.

Comment: Why are people voting this down, I've stated my answer is outdated.

Comment: Because people don't read. You might want to put an "Update" below it in the text of the answer.

Answer (score 5):

a picture is worth a thousand words

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can scale iOS simulator to desire scale (i tried from 0.2 to 1.4 ) and it worked for me. 
To do this you have to go to /Library/Preferences and edit `com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist` file. Edit value of KEY `SimulatorWindowLastScale` to your desired scale.

I tried this on latest Version of Mountain Lion 10.8.4 & iOS simulator 6.0.

Enjoy!!!! Let me know if it worked for you guys.

Comment: This is a great way to scale the simulator to exactly the size of the phone.

Comment: Cheers, In my case I found it in my user home directory so ~/Library/Preferences

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce screen size of simulator by doing this

**Window -- Scale -- 25%**  (Select size which you feel comfort)