# Force iPad retina simulator to fit on MacBook Air Screen

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

On my MB Air the iPad (retina) simulator, even at it's smallest size (50% scale) does not fit on the screen, requiring awkard scrolling.  Does anyone know of a property that can be edited or something to make it even smaller than 50%?

Comment: Where should the required pixels come from?

Comment: At 50% on the 13" MBA, the simulator should fit in landscape. That's the best you can do.

Comment: @JustSid make it 33%, or 25%, if that is too messy.  How else would it work?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the cmd key modifiers to change the size:

- Cmd+1 - original
- Cmd+2 - smaller
- Cmd+3 - smallest (this works best for me on my Macbook Air 11)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, from what I've found. [This link from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446135/reduce-the-size-of-the-iphone-simulator-window) explains,

> it seems reasonable for the accurate rendering profiling that it maintains 1-to-1 pixel ratio, otherwise it would have to sub-sample the pixels, causing the profiling to be incorrect.

I use a 13" MB, so I understand that it's difficult to fit the iPad simulator on the screen.